# How do I connect my Luxorparts keypad to my Arduino?

Tags: pins, hardware, input

I just bought a 12 digit keypad from Luxorparts and it doesn't come with any schematics showing how it's wired at all. How do I figure out how to connect it to my Arduino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a guide here that helped me out: [Keypad Tutorial](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/KeypadTutorial), that will show you the means of figuring out how the keypad is wired. I followed it and figured out that for that specific keypad (the Luxorparts keypad) the setup is as follows:

(From left to right on the keypad pins and on the rows and columns)

Pin1: Not connected
Pin2: Connected to the 2:nd collumn
Pin3: Connected to the 1:st row
Pin4: Connected to the 1:st collumn
Pin5: Connected to the 4:th row
Pin6: Connected to the 3:rd column
Pin7: Connected to the 3:rd row
Pin8: Connected to the 2:nd row
Pin9: Not connected

I modified the example code from the link above to reflect this specific Keypad:

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROW0 = 3;
const byte ROW1 = 8;
const byte ROW2 = 7;
const byte ROW3 = 5;

const byte COL0 = 4;
const byte COL1 = 2;
const byte COL2 = 6;

const byte ROWS = 4; // Four rows
const byte COLS = 3; // Three columns
// Define the Keymap
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'#','0','*'}
};
// Connect keypad ROW0, ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 to these Arduino pins.
byte rowPins[ROWS] = { ROW0, ROW1, ROW2, ROW3 };
// Connect keypad COL0, COL1 and COL2 to these Arduino pins.
byte colPins[COLS] = { COL0, COL1, COL2 }; 

// Create the Keypad
Keypad kpd = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

#define ledpin 13

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  char key = kpd.getKey();
  if(key)  // Check for a valid key.
  {
    switch (key)
    {
      case '*':
        digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);
        break;
      case '#':
        digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
        break;
      default:
        Serial.println(key);
    }
  }
}
```

To run that, simply connect each pin from the keypad, in order, to the arduino, so the second pin from the keypad goes to the second digital pin on the Arduino and so on.

I asked the question after I'd already figured out the answer in hopes of helping anyone else who bought that specific keypad.